# Tyre replacement for Rockrider 300

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, diy

I have a rockrider 300 which has tyre measurements as 26*2.0 and tube measurements as 26*1.75-26*2.12. According to the catalog they are semi-slick tyres. I want them to be even slicker.

I have looked up a btwin tyre online which measures 700*25 which is compatible with tubes measuring 700*18 - 700*25 and 700cc or 28 wheels. I am not sure what any of this means and if its a good for my bike in terms of measurements.

Can someone please give me a range of measurements of tyres and tubes that I can buy which can fit my rim.

Comment: If you have 26x2.0 tires, you need 26x (some number represented as a decimal) tires to replace it. You can use your old tubes or buy a 26x (some number range as a decimal) tube where the tire you choose is within that range. Likely you'll get something like a 26x1.75 or something slick (e.g. Continental TourRIDE/Schwalbe Marathon/etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Ah the wonderful world of tire sizes, where nothing is what it seems! There are multiple size systems (French, fractional, decimal, ISO), and only ISO/ETRTO, the "international standard" is (somewhat) consistent. Unfortunately, many people don't use the ISO/ETRTO system.

The definitive guide to tire sizes is Sheldon Browns' site:
http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html
The only thing I would like to add to the mighty Sheldon:

**Avoid** any tire with **fractional** markings (such as 26 x 1 1/4) like the plague, unless you are 100% sure what you are doing.

On to your question:

**Your current tire: 26 x 2.0**

This one of the most common MTB sizes, measured in inches:

26 in. diameter, 2.0 in. width.

**Equivalent ISO = 599mm (diameter) x 50mm (approx. width)**

**Your new Btwin tire: 700 x25c**

700 is a French size often used for road/racing cycles. Since the French like their millimetres, a 700 x 25 means "700" diameter, 25mm width. To complicate things, the French "700" is not the same as the ISO diameter...

**Equivalent ISO  =  622mm (diameter) x 25mm (width).**

Since the diameters are not the same, your new tire will not fit. There is also a large difference in tire width (50mm for the old tire, 25 for the new)

General tire selection advice:

**1)** Get the ISO diameter size right first. This is the only measure that can be somewhat relied upon.

**2)** Check tire width & rim compatibility.
Get the diameter size right first, then check the tire width. Small/skinny tires will not fit on very wide MTB rims. Fat tires will not fit on narrow rims. Measure your rim width. Sheldon Brown's site has a table that shows rim width vs. tire width compatibility.

From personal experience, I have established these quick and dirty rules regarding tire width:

Racing cycle wheels: 23mm - 30mm (but the wider tires probably will rub the frame)

City bike wheels: 30mm - 47mm

MTB wheels: 35mm- 60mm